# Mongo Atlas, mongosh alternative?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to quickly query experiment with the sample data provided by the mongo db.

If you want to experiment with the database with pure queries except for the client code, is there any way other than using the mongosh shell? They don`t provide their own web console shell?

any recommendations?

Comment: are you looking for any software/application for performing queries?

Comment: @deadshot yah I`m looking for a like "MySQL workbench" or like Planet Scale Web query console

Comment: you can try mongodb compass, robo3t, studio-3t(paid)